# How to Remove "S/O" from string?

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I am looking to remove the leading "S/O" in a string.

**Below are my current results:**

```
ID
60079804-S/O PALMER DONAVIN MFG     
60008517-S/O READY CABLE INC.
60008049-S/O ACORN INTERNATIONAL
```

**Below are my Desired Results:**

```
ID
60079804-PALMER DONAVIN MFG     
60008517-READY CABLE INC.
60008049-ACORN INTERNATIONAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select regexp_replace(id, r'\bS/O\b', '') as id
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]